# Generate a list in Magento Admin of customers that have a wishlist?

Tags: magento2.3, customer, collection, wishlist, customer-collection

I need a way to get a list of customers that have a wishlist.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load all customer and get customer have wishlist or not

currently i have pass one customer have static customer id , you can use that code by all customer

```
$customerId = 1; //Customer Id
$wishlistColl = $block->getWishlistByCustId($customerId);
if(count($wishlistColl)) {
    foreach ($wishlistColl as $_item) {
        echo $_item->getProduct()->getName();echo "<br>";
        echo $_item->getProduct()->getId();echo "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo __("No Item found in wishlist");
}
```

For Wishlist collection

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$wishlist = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Wishlist\Model\Wishlist');
```

you can load by customer id in that **loadByCustomerId**

Hope this will help you